# Select the next step in the search-in-depth style

Tags: postgresql

**Postgres 12.**

I have a table "steps" like:

```
id          | after                 | done
------------+-----------------------+---------
primary key | recursive foreign key | boolean
```

which idea is - some steps that have to be executed. `done` means that the step was done. `after` sets an order of execution and it's NULLable (when it's NULL, then it can run in any order). Otherwise, it points out the record, which have to be executed before the current. Its data may look like:

```
id  |  after  | done
----+---------+---------
1   | NULL    | true
2   | 1       | false
3   | 2       | false
4   | NULL    | true
...
```

where step=3 should run after step=2, step=2 runs after the step=1, step=1 does not depend on any order and also it was done already, step=4 does not depend too but it's done already and it's out of our interest...

I need to select `id` of the record which is ready to run. The criteria of the ready is: it should be the step which still is not done and it belongs to the **longest** "route". It means also that **multiple selects must return steps of the same "route"** (it's important requirement), so the idea is to "walk" step by step on the same (longest) "route" unless it's done totally. Then the next select will return the next undone step of the next longest "route" and so on. Something like search-in-depth: you take the longest route and go this route until its end. Then the next route...

I think it is recursive query, but I don't know how to write it.

**EDIT-1:** if some routes have equal length then any of them can be selected but every time the same one.

**EDIT-2:** after the query of the `id`, I plan to update the step's `done` (set to true), this guarantees "walking"/moving on the route.

**EDIT-3:** "multiple selects must return steps of the same route" means that the first query returns the id from the longest route (then I will update the `done` column), after it - the second query must return the next step of the same route (it's still the longest). If there are more than one longest routes (eg, 2 routes with 10 steps) then the first/last route is used and next queries should return the same route's steps (for example, always the first route).

Comment: please explain what you meen by "multiple selects must return steps of the same "route""

Comment: I just added edit 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the undone step from the longest chain of steps do:

```
CREATE TABLE steps (
    id integer primary KEY,
    after integer REFERENCES steps(id),
    done  boolean);

INSERT INTO steps 
values
    (1   , NULL    , TRUE),
    (2   , 1       , false),
    (3   , 2       , false),
    (4   , NULL    , TRUE);

WITH RECURSIVE routes(id , to_do_first , step_no ) AS (
  SELECT id, CASE WHEN done THEN NULL ELSE id END AS to_do_first, 1 AS step_no  
  FROM steps
  WHERE after IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT steps.id, 
    CASE 
      WHEN routes.to_do_first IS NOT NULL THEN routes.to_do_first 
      WHEN steps.done THEN NULL 
      ELSE steps.id 
    END AS to_do_first,
    routes.step_no + 1
  FROM steps 
    JOIN routes ON routes.id = steps.AFTER  
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  routes
WHERE 
  to_do_first IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
  step_no DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The point is you select the steps that require no steps to be taken before (after is null) as a seed and then add the steps that require steps from the prior iteration. Also I seek the first undone step in the chain of steps. After that the last step of the longest yet undone chain is returned.
`to_do_first` is the step id to be done.